# "binding reference of type discards qualifiers" when using [] operator

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I'm using C-style arrays in a c++ application (needs to interface with C code,) however I'm getting the "binding reference of type discards qualifiers" when using the [] operator on an array. Here's a small example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct outer_struct {
  struct {
    int i;
  } array[1];
} temp_struct;

typedef decltype( static_cast<outer_struct*>(nullptr)->array[0]  ) typed;

void do_something_2(const typed &thing)
{
  std::cout << thing.i << std::endl;
}

void do_something_1(const outer_struct &thing)
{
  // error: binding reference of type ‘outer_struct::<unnamed struct>&’ to
  // ‘const outer_struct::<unnamed struct>’ discards qualifiers
  do_something_2(thing.array[0]);
}

int main()
{
  temp_struct.array[0].i = 2;
  do_something_1(temp_struct);
  return 0;
}
```

I would have thought that using the [] operator on a const reference would have returned a const reference, but from the compiler output, it appears that is not the case. Changing do_something_1's signature to

```
void do_something_1(outer_struct &thing)
```

resolves the error. I normally have no problems with const correctness, but I honestly can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using g++ 7.3.0. I have tried older versions of GCC as well.

Comment: `const T&` where `T` is `U&` collapses to `U&`, not `const U&`.  (The decltyle results in a reference type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to drop extra reference returned by decltype (because result of built-in subscript operator is a reference):

```
using
inner_struct = ::std::remove_reference_t<decltype(::std::declval<outer_struct &>().array[0])>;
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CCzl9A9TRjGevzu4)